# Is there an efficient way to combine numerous subtitutions and replacements?

Tags: excel, vba, replace, case, user-defined-functions

I have a lot of data that is written in code, that I need to make more readable. For this purpose, I make use of replace in vba, especially because there is a lot of possible codes that need to be removed or replaced with different symbols, and I still need to add a few more possible texts.

The following UDF works, but whenever I find a new possible part of the code that needs to be replaced, I have to write another whole 'Let#' to compensate. I feel like there is a better way to write this function, so I was wondering if someone could help out.

```
Function Unit(Req_Header As String) As String

Dim Func As String
Dim Amount As String

Func = AkeFind(Req_Header)     'AkeFind is a different UDF that looks up the correct string in a dataset (and returns as a string)

Dim LetA As String
Dim LetB As String
Dim LetC As String
Dim LetD As String
Dim LetE As String
Dim LetF As String

LetA = Replace(Func, "formaat_papier_", "")
LetB = Replace(LetA, "motief_", "")
LetC = Replace(LetB, "materiaal_", "")
LetD = Replace(LetC, "vorm_", "")
LetE = Replace(LetD, "_", " ")
LetF = Replace(LetE, "•", "-")

Amount = LetF

    Select Case Amount
    Case "CENTIMETER", "Centimeter", "centimeter"
        Unit = "cm"
    Case "MILLIMETER", "Millimeter", "millimeter"
        Unit = "mm"
    Case "METER", "Meter", "meter"
        Unit = "m"
    Case "CENTILITER", "Centiliter", "centiliter"
        Unit = "cl"
    Case "MILLILITER", "Milliliter", "milliliter"
        Unit = "ml"
    Case "LITER", "Liter", "liter"
        Unit = "l"
    Case "KILOGRAM", "Kilogram", "kilogram"
        Unit = "kg"
    Case "MILLIGRAM", "Milligram", "milligram"
        Unit = "mg"
    Case "GRAM", "Gram", "gram"
        Unit = "g"
    Case "PIECE", "Piece", "piece"
        Unit = "Stuks"
    Case "plastic", "kunstof"
        Unit = "Kunststof"
    Case "metaal", "staal"
        Unit = "Metaal"
    Case Else
        Unit = Amount
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: I'd suggest you use a table in a worksheet of things to replace and their replacements, then just loop through it. Note: you don't need to use `Let` and you don't need a separate variable for the result of each replacement.

Comment: Your `Select Case` can also be simplified so that you don't need to check for every case : `Select Case LCase$(Amount) ... Case "centimeter" ... Case "millimeter"`

Comment: @Rory to be fair the OP didn't use Let... the variable names just started with Let.  I always get flashbacks to Sinclair & BBC Basic when I see Let. :)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I need to get my eyes tested! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on everyone's suggestions I made the following:

```
Function Unit(Req_Header As String) As String

Dim Func As String

Func = LCase$(AkeFind(Req_Header))

Dim Rem_Range As Range
Dim Replc_Range As Range
Dim a_Nr As Integer

Set Rem_Range = Sheets("Variables").Range("Rem_Table[Rem_Code]")
Set Replc_Range = Sheets("Variables").Range("Rem_Table[Replc]")

For Each a In Rem_Range
    If Func = a Then
        Unit = a.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Exit For
    Else
        Unit = Func
    End If
Next a

End Function
```

The Rem_Table is a table with the first column being each possible code, and the second column giving the appropriate term. In context this actually makes more sense to use rather than replacing parts of the code. It is also easier to add new variables that I might come across later.

Thanks for everyone's input!

Answer (score 2):

You could use something along these lines.  Requires maintainence for new units, so i'd propably go along the table approach too.  Probably best to separate out the match part of the function and test for errors before fetching from aReplace.

```
Function GetReplacementUnits(strInputUnit As String)

Dim aOrig() As Variant
Dim aReplace() As Variant

aOrig = Array("CENTIMETRE", "KILOGRAM", "METER")
aReplace = Array("cm", "Kg", "m")

GetReplacementUnits = Application.Index(aReplace, Application.Match(UCase(strInputUnit), aOrig, 0), 1)

End Function
```

Use like so

`GetReplacementUnits("CENTIMETRE")` returns cm

Comment: Nice, voted it up. You can simplify it using `GetReplacementUnits = aReplace(Application.match(UCase(strInputUnit), aOrig, 0) - 1)`... `match` already returns the necessary index (in base 1).